# Упражнения к Шилдту Полное руководство C# 4.0

Tags: c#

Читаю книгу Герберта Шилдта Полное руководство C# 4.0
Читать не сложно и разжевывается все вполне хорошо и доступно, но вот хотелось-бы еще практикой закреплять, помимо приведенных примеров в книге.
Имеется-ли что-то такое ? Возможно, задачи по этой книге, упражение или какая-то дополнительная литература. Конечно-же в приоритете, чтобы материал по книге не расходился с поставленными задачами.

Answer (score 3):

Поставьте себе большую ( для вашего нынешнего уровня знаний ) цель и реализовывайте маленькими кусочками.

--------------------------------------

Например - текстовый редактор, календарь, проигрыватель какой-то, вообщем что-то в эдакое. Не важно что именно это будет, важно чтобы вы преследовали какую-то цель кроме как "хочу быть программистом"

---------------------------------------

(да этого достаточно в принципе, но реализовывая задачи обучение происходит намного производительней)